# Merge Multiple Rows Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need a MACRO that looks at all instances of COL A and combines all values of COL B into one row, while deleting the duplicates in the process. Adding a comma is a plus.

Example of what I need:

```
COL A    COL B 
100 ---- PC 245
100 ---- PC 246
100 ---- PC 247
101 ---- PC 245
101 ---- PC 246
101 ---- PC 247
```

**INTO**

```
COL A    COL B 
100 ---- PC 245, PC 246, PC 247
101 ---- PC 245, PC 246, PC 247
```

This data is going into a map, so I need it concatenated for the tooltip text.

***PS: What I need is a MACRO. What I don't need is a PIVOT TABLE.***

Comment: Do you know any VBA?  If you've tried anything, you should edit your question to include it.

Comment: I updated the question, thanks! I don't know any VBA, but I'd like to learn so I can do this on my own in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub ConsolidateRows()
'takes rows and consolidate one or many cells, based on one or many cells matching with above or below rows.

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

'**********PARAMETERS TO UPDATE****************
Const strMatch As String = "A"    'columns that need to match for consolidation, separated by commas
Const strConcat As String = "B"     'columns that need consolidating, separated by commas
Const strSep As String = ", "     'string that will separate the consolidated values
'*************END PARAMETERS*******************

application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

colMatch = Split(strMatch, ",")
colConcat = Split(strConcat, ",")

lastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from last Row to one
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(colMatch)
        If Cells(i, colMatch(j)) <> Cells(i - 1, colMatch(j)) Then GoTo nxti
    Next
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(colConcat)
        Cells(i - 1, colConcat(j)) = Cells(i - 1, colConcat(j)) & strSep & Cells(i, colConcat(j))
    Next
    
    Rows(i).Delete
    
nxti:
Next

application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code requires you to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

```
VBA Editor->Tools->References, Find and select Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

Its possible to use "Collections" instead of "Dictionarys". I just prefer the dictionary.

The code will read the active worksheet, (the "Do Loop") and copies the data (removing duplicates in the process)

It then clears **all** data on the sheet.

It then loops through the data it collected and outputs it to the now empty worksheet (the "For Each" loops)

```
Sub Cat()
Dim Data As Dictionary
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Data = New Dictionary

Dim Row As Integer
Dim Key As Variant
Dim Keys() As Variant
Dim Value As Variant
Dim Values() As Variant
Dim List As String

Row = 1

Do
    If Data.Exists(CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 1))) Then
        If Not Data(CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 1))).Exists(CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 2))) Then
            Data(CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 1))).Add (CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 2))), True
        End If
    Else
        Data.Add CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 1)), New Dictionary
        Data(CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 1))).Add (CStr(Sheet.Cells(Row, 2))), True
    End If
    Row = Row + 1
    If IsEmpty(Sheet.Cells(Row, 1)) Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

Sheet.Cells.ClearContents

Keys = Data.Keys
Row = 1

For Each Key In Keys
    Values = Data(Key).Keys
    Sheet.Cells(Row, 1) = Key
    List = ""
    For Each Value In Values
        If List = "" Then
            List = Value
        Else
            List = List & ", " & Value
        End If
    Next Value
    Sheet.Cells(Row, 2) = List
    Row = Row + 1
Next Key

End Sub
```