# EXCEL - Macro to conditionally merge rows based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm after a VBA macro that will merge the content of the current row with that of the previous row if the content of Col C for the current row is empty

```
Input
Col A  | Col B  | Col C 
text1A | text1B | 1
text2A | text2B | 
text3A | text3B | 
text4A | text4B | 2
text5A | text5B | 

Output
Col A                | Col B                 | Col C 
text1A text2A text3A | text1B text2B test3B  | 1
text4A text5A        | text4B text5B         | 2
```

There are similar questions but my knowledge of VBA is too basic to apply the responses to this specific case. Thanks!

Comment: Code blocks really improve readablility. Either an four spaces before code or encase it with the ` character.

Comment: this is doable in vba, however your described output is different from what was shown above. please clarify. also, show the code that you've made so far and we'll start from there.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to collapse all of the content into one cell that does not have content in column C into the closest row above it that does have content in column C?

Comment: @sbanders I edited the output to reflect what I want. I tried editing the code provided at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353080/excel-merge-multiple-rows-macro> but got nowhere as I know next to no VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o) will helps you to find the solution that you needed.your question is almost a duplicate question.

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
Dim lngRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lngRow = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(1), Header:=xlYes

    Do
        If .Cells(lngRow, 1) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 1) Then
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow, 3)

            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If

        lngRow = lngRow - 1
    Loop Until lngRow = 1
End With
End Sub
```

this code worked for me .the answer is posted on the question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o)