# Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cell

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am trying to find duplicate values in one column and combine the values of a second column into one row. I also want to sum the values in a third column.

For example:

```
A    B    C    D
h    4    w    3
h    4    u    5
h    4    g    7
h    4    f    4
k    9    t    6
k    9    o    6
k    9    p    9
k    9    j    1
```

Would become

```
A    B    C        D
k    9    t;o;p;j  22
h    4    w;u;g;f  19
```

The code I have been using for the first part of this is

```
 Sub mergeCategoryValues()
Dim lngRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

lngRow = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(1), Header:=xlYes 
Do

    If .Cells(lngRow, 9) = .Cells(lngRow + 1, 9) Then
        .Cells(lngRow, 11) = .Cells(lngRow, 8) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow + 1, 8)
        .Rows(lngRow +1).Delete
    End If

    lngRow = lngRow - 1

Loop Until lngRow < 2

End With

End Sub
```

(please forgive the indentation)

The problem that I am running into is that it will find the first pair of duplicates, but not all. So I get a result that looks like this:

```
A    B    C    D
k    9    t;o  12
k    9    p;j  10   
h    4    w;u  8
h    4    g;f  11
```

Thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you considered looping through the cell using something like `for i = 65536 to 1 step -1` with `cells (i,1)` and than `cells(i -1,9)` instead of `do , loop until` ? Can't tell if this would solve your problem, until I write the code, but this is what usually works for me.

Comment: The code you have provide does not produce the result you say you are getting.  For example, it doesn't add the values in col D and the output is in column K.  Do you have other code?

Comment: @Takedasama, can you elaborate? I am new to VBA and not sure what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @Texas2014 see my answer below. Tested and working. Haven't used `cells(rowID,columnID)`,but `Range(ColumnNameRowNumber)` for a better reading of the code.

Answer (score 8):

Try changing your code to this:

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lngRow = .Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(1), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, 1) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 1) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 3) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow, 3)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, 4) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 4) + .Cells(lngRow, 4)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Tested

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To make it a little easier to adjust to different column I added variables at the beginning to indicate which column do what.  Note that column 2 (B) isn't used in the current logic.

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim lngRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1
        Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 3
        Dim columnToSum As Integer: columnToSum = 4

        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) + .Cells(lngRow, columnToSum)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Portland Runner. I ran your code, but it deleted my entire list except for the last row. It combined the columns as needed, but deleted everything except for the last record. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you run it with the exact data you posted in the exact same columns?  I just double checked it on a different machine and got good results.  It shouldn't delete everything unless values in column A are all identical.

Comment: Looks like your comment got cut off.  I updated the post with new code that uses variables for each column.  Now you can easily change the variables at the top to account for different columns in your sheet.

Comment: The example I gave was an abbreviated version of the data I have. I did not think that changing the cell reference numbers would change the code, but now I realize how stupid that was. I reformatted my data and your code worked perfectly. Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 1):

This looks sloppy and complicated. Both are true, but it works pretty fine.
**Note!** I always recommend to define all `DIM`s like: ranges, integers, etc. Storing the last row to a variable like `LngRow` is best (not like the whole `App.WksFunc.COUNTA`). I also like to use functions directly on cells where possible (like the `SUMIFS` ex. below). Thus, **based on your example configuration (columns ABCD)**:

```
Sub Test_Texas2014()
Dim MySheet As Worksheet: Set MySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

'Clear the previous results before populating 
MySheet.Range("F:I").Clear

'Step1 Find distinct values on column A and copy them on F
For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("A:A"))
    Row_PasteCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("F:F")) + 1
    Set LookupID = MySheet.Range("A" & i)
    Set LookupID_SearchRange = MySheet.Range("F:F")
    Set CopyValueID_Paste = MySheet.Range("F" & Row_PasteCount)
        If IsError(Application.Match(LookupID, LookupID_SearchRange, 0)) Then
            LookupID.Copy
            CopyValueID_Paste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
Next i

'Step2 fill your values in columns G H I based on selection
For j = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("F:F"))
    Set ID = MySheet.Range("F" & j)
    Set Index = MySheet.Range("G" & j)
    Set AttributeX = MySheet.Range("H" & j)
    Set SumX = MySheet.Range("I" & j)
    For k = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("A:A"))
        Set SearchedID = MySheet.Range("A" & k)
        Set SearchedID_Index = MySheet.Range("B" & k)
        Set SearchedID_AttributeX = MySheet.Range("C" & k)
        Set SearchedID_SumX = MySheet.Range("D" & k)
            If ID.Value = SearchedID.Value Then
                Index.Value = SearchedID_Index.Value
                AttributeX.Value = AttributeX.Value & ";" & SearchedID_AttributeX.Value
                SumX.Value = SumX.Value + SearchedID_SumX.Value
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub

'Although for the sum I would use something like:
MySheet.Range("I1").Formula = "=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,F1)"
MySheet.Range("I1").Copy
MySheet.Range("I2:I" & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("I:I"))).pasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
'Similar for the Index with a Vlookup or Index(Match())
```

Answer (score 1):

Merging rows by summing the numbers from column D and building a string concatenation from column C with a semi-colon delimiter based upon duplicate values in columns A and B.

Before¹:

[image: Merge Data Before]

Code:

```
Sub merge_A_to_D_data()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, str As String, dbl As Double
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Key2:=.Columns(2), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        lr = .Rows.Count
        For rw = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, 1).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 1).Value2 And _
               .Cells(rw, 2).Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, 2).Value2 And rw < lr Then
                .Cells(rw, 4) = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(rw, 4), .Cells(lr, 4)))
                .Cells(rw, 3) = Join(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(rw, 3), .Cells(lr, 3))), Chr(59))
                .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(lr - rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                lr = rw - 1
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After¹:

[image: Merge Data After]

¹<sub>Some additional rows of data were added to the original posted data in order to demonstrate the sort.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
Sub MyCombine()
Dim i As Integer
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A"), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:D")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlStroke
    .Apply
End With

i = 2

Do Until Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & ";" & Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
        Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value + Cells(i + 1, 4).Value
        Rows(i + 1).Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Cells(lngRow, 11) = .Cells(lngRow, 8) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow + 1, 8)`

should be

`.Cells(lngRow, 11) = .Cells(lngRow, 8) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow + 1, 11)`

Comment: Thanks for adding the backticks Teja

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
If StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
If Range("C" & lngRow) <> "" Then
Range("C" & lngRow - 1) = Range("C" & lngRow - 1) & ";" & Range("C" & lngRow)
Range("D" & lngRow - 1) = Range("D" & lngRow - 1) + Range("D" & lngRow)
End If
Rows(lngRow).Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```