# How to concatenate unique values in column B by singular values in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns representing a 1:many relationship. I need to reduce this down to a 1:1 relationship where the many in columnn B are concatenated by commas. Data below:

```
zipcode neighbors
10001   10010
10001   10011
10001   10016
10001   10018
10001   10119
10001   10199
10003   10012
```

Here is what I want the output to look like:

```
zipcode neighbors
10001   10010, 10011, 10012, 10016, 10018, 10019, 10199
```

There are 9000 records so I need to run a loop until end of record.

Now sure how to do this.

---

I figured it out, thanks everyone. Code share below:

```
Sub Concatenate()

Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim result As String
Dim counter As Integer

oldValue = ""
newValue = ""
result = ""
counter = 1

For i = 2 To 9401

newValue = Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 1)

If (oldValue <> newValue) Then

    Worksheets("result").Cells(counter, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
    Worksheets("result").Cells(counter, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
    Worksheets("result").Cells(counter, 1) = oldValue
    Worksheets("result").Cells(counter, 2) = result
    counter = counter + 1
    result = ""

End If

If (result = "") Then
    result = Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 2)
Else
    result = result + "," + Worksheets("data").Cells(i, 2)
End If

oldValue = newValue

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that was a poor example, but hopefully the idea gets accross

Comment: I can give you the answer but I want you to try first. Here is one way. It's a VBA Method. `1` Get unique Zipcodes from the list using collections `2` Loop through the unique collection and then in the inner loop, loop through Col A. For every match, concatenate the values `3` Output to New Sheet

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Or a dictionary. Tested this on 15,000 records and it's fairly fast at 0.23 seconds.

Comment: @BK201: `Collection/Dict/Array` are faster :)

Comment: I've replied a similar question a few weeks ago. You should have a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o)! also. Practically you just need the A and C columns from that example

Answer (score 2):

Bravo for figuring it out. Here's a separate task that can process 15,000 records in less than a second (YMMV machine-wise, of course).

My data:

[image]

The code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetByDictionary()
    Dim wBk As Workbook: Set wBk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wSht As Worksheet: Set wSht = wBk.Sheets("Sheet5") 'Modify accordingly.
    Dim oDict As Object: Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim lLastRow As Long: lLastRow = wSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Dim rZIP As Range: Set rZIP = wSht.Range("A2:A" & lLastRow)
    Dim rNeigh As Variant, rCl As Range, rNewZIP As Range, rCl2 As Range
    Dim Start As Variant

    Start = Timer()
    'Store zipcodes and neighbors into dictionary.
    With oDict
        For Each rCl In rZIP
            rNeigh = rCl.Offset(, 1).Value
            If Not .Exists(rCl.Value) And Not IsEmpty(rCl.Value) Then
                .Add rCl.Value, rNeigh
            Else
                .Item(rCl.Value) = .Item(rCl.Value) & ", " & rNeigh
            End If
        Next rCl
    End With

    'Output them somewhere.
    With wSht
        .Range("E1").Value = "zipcode"
        .Range("F1").Value = "neighbors"
        Set rNewZIP = .Range("E2").Resize(oDict.Count)
        rNewZIP.Value = Application.Transpose(oDict.Keys)
        For Each rCl2 In rNewZIP
            rCl2.Offset(0, 1).Value = oDict.Item(rCl2.Value)
        Next rCl2
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer() - Start

End Sub
```

The result:

[image]

0.31 seconds to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on your query. This is based on a previous answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o/20363158#20363158)

```
Sub Test_User4015()
Dim MySheet As Worksheet: Set MySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

'Clear the previous results before populating
MySheet.Range("F:G").Clear

'Step1 Find distinct values on column A and copy them on F
    For i = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("A:A"))
    Row_PasteCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("F:F")) + 1
    Set LookupID = MySheet.Range("A" & i)
    Set LookupID_SearchRange = MySheet.Range("F:F")
    Set CopyValueID_Paste = MySheet.Range("F" & Row_PasteCount)
        If IsError(Application.Match(LookupID, LookupID_SearchRange, 0)) Then
            LookupID.Copy
            CopyValueID_Paste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i

'Step2 fill your values in column(s) G based on selection
    For j = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("F:F"))
    Set ID = MySheet.Range("F" & j)
    Set Neighbor = MySheet.Range("G" & j)
For k = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(MySheet.Range("A:A"))
    Set SearchedID = MySheet.Range("A" & k)
    Set SearchedID_Neighbor = MySheet.Range("B" & k)
        If ID.Value = SearchedID.Value Then
            Neighbor.Value = Neighbor.Value & "," & SearchedID_Neighbor.Value
        End If
    Next k
Next j
End Sub
```

**Note!** The Code is tested and working. Hope this helps,

**Edit** I've just read you needed this to cover app 10k rows. This is working, but is *VERY* slow on such a range. better stick to something else for bigger tables.