# Excel: How do I 'gather' values to display in another cell

Tags: excel

I have two columns, Column A has a set of a few standard values and column B has all unique values. I'm only just experimenting with more complex ways of compiling data than the beginner level so I'm a bit at a loss.

I need to either have a lookup or create a macro that will list only the values in A (once each) but also display which values in B correspond to those in A

for example

```
A | B 
va1|abc
va1|bcd
Va2|xyz
va3|zab
```

will show (in a single cell) the following

```
va1: abc, bcd
va2: xyz
va3: zab
```

Please help!

Comment: Doesn't a "pivot table" solve your problem?

Comment: @DanielMöller no, a pivot table will not return strings, only count of strings.

Comment: What have you tried so far? a search online for "excel formula unique values in column" yields several results including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429899/getting-unique-values-in-excel-by-using-formulas-only)

Comment: tried the pivot table route but that only provides a list but isn't dynamic. I forgot to mention that column A and B will be a paste of data from an external source. Trying to find the simplest solution as this is the only pending field that I need to populate from a bunch of other things that run with a one click macro I have set up.

Comment: This will take vba.  Formulas will not be able to do this

Comment: yea I though so VBA is the route...and I'm all up for using VBA (been fiddling with it lately and have a whole bunch of other things runinng on VBA macro on this workbook). but I can't seem to come up with a decent query to find the appropriate results :(

Comment: If you put both columns in the "left side" of the pivot table, you will get everything grouped and listed.

Comment: Add the vba tags and show what you have to this point that is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557489/how-to-concatenate-unique-values-in-column-b-by-singular-values-in-column-a

Comment: Do you really need "single strings" or groups suffice?

Comment: @SJR thanks for that link. it's perfect! Managed to use that successfully. and then will use another cell to compile the results all in one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

k = 1

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Application.CountIf(Range("C:C"), Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 Then
        Cells(k, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value

        For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(k, 3).Value And _
               InStr(Cells(k, 4).Value, Cells(j, 2).Value) = 0 Then
                If Cells(k, 4).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(k, 4).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value
                Else
                    Cells(k, 4).Value = Cells(k, 4).Value & ", " & Cells(j, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next j

        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & ": " & Cells(i, 4).Value
    Cells(i, 4).ClearContents
Next i

End Sub
```

**Edited for single cell**

[image: img2]

Comment: oh this is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case your requirement is to "have the grouped data", and not exactly "have one single string per A", you can do this with a "pivot table" putting A and B in the row labels, like in the following picture:

[image: picture]

Comment: +1 as I think this is much more piratical solution. Later down the road, the single string output may need to be parsed which will lead to extra work just to arrive here.