# Merge cells depending on a value in column for a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I need to add data in row G, and merge Date in row A if row E has same strings. I found [Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o), which is very helpful but I need to do it for a range G7:G65536, because my rows from 1 to 6 are merged.

Is there a way I can adapt this code?

I was trying to play around with it but it did not give me any results.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some sample data of what the before and after is like they did in the linked post? You might be able to get a better response if you're more clear about what it is you're having trouble with.

Comment: If the biggest obstacle is that *'my rows from 1 to 6 are merged'* then change one line in that code to `Loop Until lngRow < 7`.

Comment: It gives me _'application-defined or object defined error'_, or if I change it to `Loop Until lngRow = 7` then it again says _'The application requires the merged cells to be identically sized'_

Comment: Tyler, I was trying to add i = 7 to 65536 and i = 65536 to 7 (just in case) and substitute it here `lngRow = .Cells(i, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row` does not work

Comment: a) what columns are duplicated? b) are there any other columns besides G to be aggregated or concatenated? The example you cited sums one column and concatenates another. c) is row 7 a column header row or the first row of data?

Comment: a) there are no duplicated columns, there are duplicated values of cells in column G. b) there are actually other columns besides G, but I don't need them, I can use them to search too (columns B, C, D, F), but I think G is enough for search, I want to concatenate column A, so I can see the list of dates when the product was added to this sheet, and the total sum of this product available in column G, Column E contains product name by which I want to search. c) 6th row is a header. 7th is the first row of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used your comments to come up with the following sample data.

[image: Row data merge before]

I suspect that the idea is to use column **E** as the unique key column and aggregate (aka SUM) the quantities from column **G** while building a concatenated list of dates from column A. The first 6 rows of the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) is to be ignored as there are at least some [Range.MergeCells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197310.aspx) with joined [Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174786%28v=office.11%29.aspx) in the first six rows. TBH, I found your original narrative contradicted your most recent comments so I have used the latter as the 'discovery'.

```
Sub merge_some_row_data()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, s As Long, str As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        With .Cells(7, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 6, .Columns.Count)
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(5), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(1), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
        lr = .Rows.Count
        For rw = .Rows.Count To 7 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, "E").Value2 <> .Cells(rw - 1, "E").Value2 And rw < lr Then
                .Cells(rw, "G") = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(rw, "G"), .Cells(lr, "G")))
                str = vbNullString
                For s = rw To lr
                    str = str & Chr(59) & .Cells(s, "A").Text    'Chr(59) is the ASCII code for a semi-colon
                Next s
                .Cells(rw, "A") = Mid(str, 2)  'truncate off the firsty semi-colon
                .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(lr - rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                lr = rw - 1
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After running the code, the results resembled the following.

[image: Row data merge after]

If you have any trouble at all transcribing this framework for your own super-secret purposes, feel free to revise your original question with redacted sample data together with expected results and the portion of this code that you cannot fit into your own situation.

Comment: This works awesome! Thanks a lot. Also, may I ask you. I just have multiple worksheets where I want this code to run (Sheet 2, 5, 8, 11,14,17,20,23,26,29) after I press the button merge. Is it possible to run this code not for the active sheet only?

Comment: There are several ways to loop through each worksheet in a workbook or through a limited selection of worksheets using an array of their names. In fact, the above code's `With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion` need only be enveloped in another loop that identifies each worksheet to be processed.

Comment: Well, I used `Dim WshtNames As Variant, InxW As Long` `WshtNames = Array(Sheet2, Sheet5, Sheet8, Sheet11, Sheet14, Sheet17, Sheet20, Sheet23, Sheet26, Sheet29)` `For InxW = LBound(WshtNames) To UBound(WshtNames)` `Worksheets(WshtNames(InxW)).Activate` and after `With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion` I have `Next InxW`. It gives me object-defined error. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry, could you edit your code so it searches by column E and adds #s in column G, I was trying to do it myself but when I switch E for G and G for E in your code one product overwrites another.

Comment: I suspect you did not change the primary sort column. This is important as it is used as the key to find like products.