# Combine Rows based on duplicate values in column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

***NOTE: I'm on my second day of searching this site and have not found a good answer that works or that I'm able to understand. I do not know coding and this is just for work. (I don't have time to learn it in the next 6 hours). Please assist, as what I've seen does not answer the problem I have. I've posted one of the many VBA codes I've tried at the bottom. It looks close to what I need, but I do not know how to edit it for MY data. ***

I have a vendor that separates job numbers based on who worked on a part of that job no matter how many times we ask that they put all of the information in one row.  So my question is, how do I combine the rows based on the job number? There are multiple columns that are associated with the rows that need to be combined, A-P or 1-16, with column A/1 containing the duplicate job numbers. I do not need sums as all of the columns are text or dates. I just need the rows combined and if there are more than one distinct entry for a column to have the comments separated by a comma. For instance:

[image: example]

The first two rows are examples of what I'm receiving and the fifth row is what I need (I've hidden some columns for the example). So as you see, any column with duplicate values are condensed, columns that only have 1 entry just copies that single entry and columns with multiple different entries combines all of the entries into one cell and separates each with a comma.

I know it seems simple to do by hand, but some of these job numbers are duplicated 20 times and I have 600+ of these to go through every week when the vendor submits the info incorrectly again.

Here is one of the VBA codes I've tried. This is the original. I won't show you how I tried to edit it for my work... bc I know it was horrible. PLEASE ASSIST!

Sub mergeCategoryValues()
    Dim lngRow As Long

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1
    Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 3
    Dim columnToSum As Integer: columnToSum = 4

    lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

    Do
        If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & "; " & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) + .Cells(lngRow, columnToSum)
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If

        lngRow = lngRow - 1
    Loop Until lngRow = 1
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly highly encourage you to spend the time to learn what this is doing. I have made copious comments in the code and changed around your example code to merge all rows with similar job numbers together.

I haven't tested the code, but it should do the job. Make sure to test it first before allowing to eat up all of your data.

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues() 
    Dim lngRow As Long

    'This is using activesheet, so make sure your worksheet is 
    ' selected before running this code.
    With ActiveSheet

        'We are looking for duplicate Job Numbers
        '  which is column 1. Set that here if it needs
        '  to change.
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1

        'Figure out the last row
        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row

        'Sort the records by the column we will use to match . Column A holds the Job Number
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        'Loop through each row starting with last and working our way up.
        Do

            'Does this row match with the next row up accoding to the Job Number in Column A?
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then

                'Loop through columns B though P
                For i = 2 to 16

                    'Determine if the next row up already has a value. If it does leave it be
                    '   if it doesn't then use the value from this row to populate the next
                    '   next one up.
                    If .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).value = "" Then
                        .cells(lngRow - 1, i).value = .cells(lngRow, i).value
                    End if
                Next i

                'Now that we've processed all of the columns, delete this row
                '   as the next row up will have all the values
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            'Go to the next row up and do it all again.
            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I get a couple of syntax errors with this code. 

                For i = 2 through 16

                        .cells(lngRow - 1, i)value = .cells(lngRow, i).value

Comment: I'm sorry for being a newbie at this. I promise to learn VBA soon! lol

Comment: Sorry... yes that should be `for i = 2 to 16` I will update. And I missed a period in that other line. Should be good now.  No worries on the not knowing VBA. If you get tasked with more stuff like this, then you'd be doing yourself a huge favor by learning it. If you can work your way through understanding just this bit of code, then you'll be more proficient then most.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!