# Trouble filtering, outputting, and shorting this data

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
Brain melted. I know Stackoverflow doesn't do free coding, but I'm stuck on how to start. I'm trying to filter and output the data from the left side to look like the data on the right side using VBA scripting. Any suggestion on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: (1) Read source name from first record, search for it in destination names.  If not found, add name to destination names.  (2) Find source name in destination names (it will definitely now be there) and update other column(s) to be "x" if corresponding source column is "x" (3) Repeat for next record.  (There are probably easier ways to do this, but I'm hungry and not thinking straight at the moment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
  Dim lngRow As Long

  With ActiveSheet
      Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 2
      Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 4
      Dim columnToSum As Integer: columnToSum = 5

      lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
      .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

      Do
          If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
              .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
              .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToSum) + .Cells(lngRow, columnToSum)
              .Rows(lngRow).Delete
          End If

          lngRow = lngRow - 1
      Loop Until lngRow = 1
  End With
End Sub
```

It was adapted from this code: [Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o)
All you need to figure out is to remove the first column and to make the variables more dynamic.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help, have a nice day.