# VBA Excel, PHP MySQL - data loop, transponse, range, list views, arrays

Tags: php, mysql, excel, vba

As shown in the image above, I'm trying to achieve a result as shown in AFTER table from the data in BEFORE table.

**These are what I want us to achieve:**

1. Uniquely transpose department from columns into rows
2. Uniquely List all vendor that is tired to each location, office and department - separated by comma for multiple vendors

I have so far been able to write a sub routine that is able to copy the department data and transpose it, but I'm stock moving forward.

```
Range("D4:D18").Select
Range("D4:D18").Sort key1:=Range("D4"), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
Selection.Copy
Range("CJ3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

and giving it a try on mySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location, department, office, GROUP_CONCAT(vendor) as vendor FROM `tbl_dep_ven_location` WHERE department = 'Procurement' and location = 'Femty' GROUP BY office ORDER by depterment
```

Comment: What are you doing with php ?

Comment: @Vityata : kindly see image here [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwn4h.png), was not able to able to post image since i am new and need 10 reputation... Solutions in PHP or Excel VBA is welcome.

Comment: There are many examples online of combining rows based on certain columns in VBA - have you tried searching?

Comment: @SJR you sure right,  i did some search to arrive at the stated script... and i am still researching... glad if you can make it more easier... do you have any link

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227196/excel-vba-combine-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-one-cell-and-merge-values-in-o

Comment: @SJR : thanks for the link... i am trying to see how to move the result to another range, instead of deleting original data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an efficient query but it will do the job.

```
SELECT 
    A.location as location,
    A.office as office,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor) as Admin 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Admin'
    ) as Admin,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor) as Commerce 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Commerce'
    ) as Commerce,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor) as Law 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Law'
    ) as Law,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor) as Procurement 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Procurement'
    ) as Procurement 
    FROM tbl_dep as A 
    GROUP BY A.location,A.office
    ORDER BY A.location,A.office
```

If you decide that you want the vendor order to be alphabetically sorted you just have to add an ORDER BY clause inside the GROUP_CONCAT function.
As shown in the following SQL.

```
SELECT 
    A.location as location,
    A.office as office,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor ORDER BY vendor) as Admin 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Admin'
    ) as Admin,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor ORDER BY vendor) as Commerce 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Commerce'
    ) as Commerce,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor ORDER BY vendor) as Law 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Law'
    ) as Law,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(vendor ORDER BY vendor) as Procurement 
        FROM tbl_dep 
        WHERE location = A.location and office = A.office and department='Procurement'
    ) as Procurement 
    FROM tbl_dep as A 
    GROUP BY A.location,A.office
    ORDER BY A.location,A.office
```

Comment: super thanks for this, it worked like charm, is there a way to implement a sort on the vendor results.

Comment: super thanks, will need to be you student on SQL Queries.

Comment: Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'A.location' in 'where clause'

Comment: Check that the 'tbl_dep as A' alias appears in the query. If you are attempting to run sub-queries independently for testing you must replace all references to A.column_name with static values for a specific instance of that column.  I also updated the query above to ensure that the outer most query group by and order by use the alias A for column references

Comment: found with testing you were correct, the alias reference did not work. I did find there is an 'ORDER BY' clause available within the 'GROUP_CONCAT' function that makes the issue redundant. The SQL statement was updated to make use of it instead.